# Cannot upload artifact to Nexus Sonatype using Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle, nexus

I am trying to start using Nexus (version 2.X) as a local Maven repository.
I have been searching for a way to auto upload my dependencies to Nexus, but I can't manage to get it to work.

Using Gradle 4.1, Java 8 and InteliJIdea, if it matters.

My `build.gradle` file is as follows:

```
group 'myGroupName'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin:'maven'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version: '3.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.6'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/") {
                authentication(userName: "admin", password: "admin123")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have uploaded the `commons-math3-3.5.jar` manually, and trying to use `uploadArchives` to upload `commons-lang3-3.6` automatically.

The error I get is

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6.
  Required by:
      project :
   > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6.
      > Could not get resource 'http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.6/commons-lang3-3.6.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.6/commons-lang3-3.6.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

I have also tried `compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6"` instead of `compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.6'`, to match it with [Nexus Build Grade Example](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/blob/master/gradle/simple-project/build.gradle), and also tried to add

```
task wrapper( type: Wrapper, description: "create a gradlew" ) {
gradleVersion = '4.1'
}
```

but it didn't work.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Why `localhost:8081`? Do you have `settings.xml` with this address somewhere?

Comment: I have this in my settings.xml (copied that from somewhere):
&lt;<strong><span style="color: blue">url</span></strong>&gt;http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty&lt;<strong><span style="color: blue">/url</span></strong>&gt;

Answer (score 2):

There is no full error message, but it looks like you have error during compilation stage. I assume it was unable to download from Nexus dependencies needed for compilation. Try adding `jcenter()` in repositories section to work around it. 
Alternatively you can provide a valid credentials for your Nexus in the maven configuration

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/"
        credentials {
                username "user"
                password "password"
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest also using maven-publish plugin https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

BTW the example you are using is outdated. I suggest using examples bundled with Gradle or from their documentation.

Comment: there is clear error `Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized`

Comment: @rkosegi I meant that there's no previous Gradle messages and it's not clear what it tried to do. My understanding is that it was unable to download dependencies needed for compilation. It's probably due to the Nexus misconfiguration, but adding jcenter() should work around it.

Comment: My problem is not downloading dependencies from Nexus, as the code compiles when I mark the "coomons-lang3" library as a comment.
The problem is that I am trying to auto upload dependencies to Nexus, yet fails to do so.

Comment: @GalMor as long as dependency is specified Gradle tries to download it regardless if you actually use it in your code. Does the upload to Nexus works with the commented  "commons-lang3" library?

Comment: No.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.sigmabit.nexus-maven:example:jar:1.0-20171008.080706-1 from/to remote (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/): Failed to transfer file: htt
p://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/com/sigmabit/nexus-maven/example/1.0-SNAPSHOT/example-1.0-20171008.080706-1.jar. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request.

What is this snapshot it tries to transfer?

Comment: @GalMor the snapshot should be your compiled application.

Comment: Well I can't have a compiled application without importing the relevant jars, and I want to upload those jars to Nexus automatically, then getting them from Nexus for my projects.
So now I am in a weird loop as I understand it.

Comment: @GalMor OSS libraries like commons-lang3 should be downloaded by Nexus from internet. It's not something that you should upload manually.

Comment: @GalMor I guess it is incorrect Nexus configuration. In any way it is way beyond scope of your question and probably not related to Stack Overflow at all.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "https://www.acme.com/nexus/content/repositories/com.acme.snapshots/"
            credentials {
                username "admin"
                password "admin123"
            }
        }
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
```

Comment: buildscript configuration can be sometimes required to use 3rd party plugins, but it is not that author tries to do

Comment: Trying that I got it to auto download the "commons-lang3" library (not exactly what I wanted to do, as I already had the jar on my machine), but it was unable to execute "aploadArchives" successfully.
Could it be that I need to change the url in the last repository?